# jQuery - Can't bind events to DOM dynamically created elements

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I can use `on` in elements that already exists in the page, but if I try to use it on elements that are dynamically created by the page, the events doesn't fire.
I've tried to alert the dynamic created element count in the page using `length` and it says it's 0.
Is there a specific way to bind events to dynamically created elements from my extension JS file? 
  I'm loading my JS file in `manifest.json` in `content_scripts`.
The JS event binding script that I'm using is:

```
$(document).on('click','#myBtn',function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Cool",
  "description": "Description.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://forum.com.br/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "core.js"]
    }
]
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/fq70unk8/

Comment: Well ids are singular....and that code should work.

Comment: I'll do this for some spans too, but it doesn't work with spans nor this button.

Comment: check if the same id "myBtn" should not be present already in your page . You can check that in console $("#myBtn") and then "Reveal in Elements panel" .Check whether it's the same button on which you are binding click event ?

Comment: @TusharRaj, yes, I can find it by it's id when I run this command in the page.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's the only element on the page with this id?

Comment: Yes, I copy pasted the code $("#myBtn") into Chrome console, and it returned the element, my guess is that the chrome extension JS, for some reason, can't detect dynamycally created elements.

Comment: Then you have to "right click" on that output and click "Reveal elementes in the panel " it will take you to the respective DOM . Then check from there , whether it's the same button or not ? I hope this time i am clear to you :P

Comment: @BernardoLima I'm not 100% sure if it is possible, but the page's code can potentially prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: @BernardoLima Can you provide `content_scripts` part in the question?

Comment: Xan thanks for the tip, I'll check to see if that might be happening. Ramsharan, I've edited the post with my manifest file.

Comment: I believe we need the page in question and your code to create the element.

Comment: @Xan, this jsfiddle is exactly like in the page: http://jsfiddle.net/fq70unk8/, except that in the page, the element is created when you click in a button.

Comment: It works because it's the JS from the page, I think that using a chrome extension that adds your custom JS file to a target page might work different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created simple google-chrome-extension project which contains jquery-1.11.1.js, manifest.json and myscript.js files.

manifest.json contains

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "test extension",
    "description": "This extension is for test.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
                ],
            "js": ["jquery-1.11.1.js","myscript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and myscript.js contains

```
console.log("log from extension");
$("#header").on('click','#formSubmit',function(){
  alert('Okey');
});
```

I have loaded this extension project in google-chrome and open [this question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041957/jquery-cant-bind-events-to-dom-dynamically-created-elements) and added manually `<span id="formSubmit" <a href="#" class="formSubmit" tabindex="3">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>` in `<div id="header">` using inpect element and clicking that 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' gives alert with 'Okey'.

Comment: Was the span dynamically added?

Comment: I have added it manually after the document is loaded. So it can be called dynamic.

Comment: I have added the span using `document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = '<span id="formSubmit" <a href="#" class="formSubmit" tabindex="3">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></span>'` after the page is loaded and it worked.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I'll take a deeper look into that later today.

Comment: Ok. You can also look about `run_at`.